# REST dataset for Copy Activity Source give me error Invalid PaginationRule

Tags: azure-data-factory

My Copy Activity is setup to use a REST Get API call as my source. I keep getting Error Code 2200 Invalid PaginationRule RuleKey=supportRFC5988.

I can call the GET Rest URL using the Web Activity, but this isn't optimal as I then have to pass the output to a stored procedure to load the data to the table. I would much rather use the Copy Activity.

Any ideas why I would get an Invalid PaginationRule error on a call?

I'm using a REST Linked Service with the following properties:
Name: Workday
Connect via integration runtime: link-unknown-self-hosted-ir
Base URL: https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service
Authentication type: Basic
User name: Not telling
Azure Key Vault for password
Server Certificate Validation is enabled
Parameters: Name:format Type:String Default value:json
Datasource:

```
    "name": "Workday_Test_REST_Report",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "Workday",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference",
            "parameters": {
                "format": "json"
            }
        },
        "folder": {
            "name": "Workday"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "RestResource",
        "typeProperties": {
            "relativeUrl": "/customreport2/company1/person%40company.com/HIDDEN_BI_RaaS_Test_Outbound"
        },
        "schema": []
    }
}

Copy Activity 

{
    "name": "Copy Test Workday REST API output to a table",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "RestSource",
                        "httpRequestTimeout": "00:01:40",
                        "requestInterval": "00.00:00:00.010",
                        "requestMethod": "GET",
                        "paginationRules": {
                            "supportRFC5988": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlMISink",
                        "tableOption": "autoCreate"
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Workday_Test_REST_Report",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Destination_db",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "schema": "ELT",
                            "tableName": "WorkdayTestReportData"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "folder": {
            "name": "Workday"
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after posting this, I noticed that in the copy activity code there is a nugget about `"supportRFC5988": "true"` I switched the true to false, and everything just worked for me.  I don't see a way to change this in the Copy Activity GUI

Answer (score 0):

Editing source code and setting this option to false helped!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).